# Use data provided by array_count_values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have created an array that takes some data from a DB and enters it into the array.

Using array_count_values, I also find out how many times each value appears in the array, and the resulting array looks like this:

Original code:

```
$winnersarray = array();
$winnersresults=mysql_query("SELECT r.driverId FROM results r JOIN calendar c ON r.eventID=c.id WHERE c.event='$eventName' AND c.competition='$competition_id' AND r.position='1' AND r.eventSession NOT IN ('T','P','Q','Q1','Q2','QA')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($winnersresults)) {
    $winnersarray[]=$row['driverId'];
}

print_r(array_count_values($winnersarray));
```

Array printed:

`Array ( [887] => 1 [191] => 1 [94] => 2 [253] => 1 [578] => 1 [50] => 2 [4] => 1 [179] => 1 [59] => 1 [95] => 1 [333] => 2 [936] => 1 )`

At this point, I get stuck. What I am aiming to achieve is a table that features the number of instances the value appears (i.e. 2 for user 94, user 50 and user 333), and other data using these IDs (namely, the username associated to it and the IDs of the events where that ID was in position 1).

Any pointer in the right direction is welcome!

**EDIT**: a similar table, from wikipedia, showing how I would want my final table data to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0h6F.png
The table is sorted by number of wins, which is also something I need to do with the above data.

PS - i know mysql is depreciated - I am going through legacy code and updating to mysqli as I go. The site is a good 4-5 years old so there is quite a bit to tinker!

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thank you - I added a link to an image of how it should result.

Comment: @chris85 would this be as part of the original array or in its stead?

Comment: Instead, that should replace your current query and give you a count for each ID.

Comment: @chris85 thank you - this gives me the association between the user and the number of instances, but it sorts it by user id. Is there any way to sort it by the number of instances (descending)? Or is it not possible as that is something we find out only as we proceed?

Comment: @chris85 works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using just SQL, no need for the PHP array functions. Use SQL's `group by`, `count` and `order by`. Here's how it should work:

```
SELECT count(r.driverId) as count, r.driverId 
FROM results r 
JOIN calendar c 
ON r.eventID=c.id 
WHERE c.event='$eventName' AND 
c.competition='$competition_id' AND 
r.position='1' AND 
r.eventSession NOT IN ('T','P','Q','Q1','Q2','QA') 
group by r.driverId 
order by count desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!